# How to download multiple plots with only one download button in R shiny?

Tags: r, plot, shiny

**[See my failed attempt to address this question with ggsave per YBS answer, failed MWE at the very bottom in case anyone knows what I'm doing wrong.]** Original question: I would like to download multiple plots with the click of one download button (to prevent an overly-cluttered screen).  All plots would go to the download directory, as separate PNG files.

In the below MWE code I have the download button working for the first plot but I haven't been able to figure out how to include the 2nd plot. Without adding a second button!

I'd like the downloaded file to be .PNG (as the below does).

In the full App this MWE is extracted from, there are several more plots and not just the 2 shown in this MWE.

Any thoughts on how to do this?

Here's the MWE code:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y        
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE]) 
  b[b<=0] <- NA               
  b <- c(1,b)                 
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a) 
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]         
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x) 
  b <- seq(1:x) 
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a) 
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z       
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)] 
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}   
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y  
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)                                     
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){
  vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

matrix.link <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))})}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                 
                 downloadButton("downloadData", "Download"),
                 
                 uiOutput("vectorTable")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  vector1_input <- reactive(input$vector1_input)
  yld           <- reactiveValues()
  
  vectorVariable <- function(x,y){
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(input$periods,x)
    else vector.multiFinal(input$periods,matrix.validate(input$periods,y))}
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))))})
  
  renderUI({
    matrix.link("vector_input",input$base_input[1,1])
    matrix.link("vector1_input",input$base_input[2,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),
            matrix2.input("vector1_input",input$periods,input$base_input[2,1]))})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())))
  output$graph2 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input())))
  
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {paste("yieldVector","png",sep=".")},
    content = function(file){
      png(file)
      plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input()))
      dev.off()}
  ) # close download handler
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({vectorsAll()})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{yld$showme <- tagList(plotOutput("graph1"), plotOutput("graph2"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{yld$showme <- DTOutput("table1")})
  
  output$vectorTable <- renderUI({yld$showme})
  
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    cbind(1:periods(),
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())[,2],
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input())[,2])})})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Here´s my MWE failed attempt to use `ggsave` to download multiple plots, just beneath the commented-out section under `Server`:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y        
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE]) 
  b[b<=0] <- NA               
  b <- c(1,b)                 
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a) 
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]         
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x) 
  b <- seq(1:x) 
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a) 
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z       
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)] 
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}   
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y  
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)                                     
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){
  vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

matrix.link <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))})}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                 
                 actionButton("download", "Download"),
                 
                 uiOutput("vectorTable")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  vector1_input <- reactive(input$vector1_input)
  yld           <- reactiveValues()
  
  vectorVariable <- function(x,y){
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(input$periods,x)
    else vector.multiFinal(input$periods,matrix.validate(input$periods,y))}
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))))})
  
  renderUI({
    matrix.link("vector_input",input$base_input[1,1])
    matrix.link("vector1_input",input$base_input[2,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),
            matrix2.input("vector1_input",input$periods,input$base_input[2,1]))})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())))
  output$graph2 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input())))
  
  # output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  #   filename = function() {paste("yieldVector","png",sep=".")},
  #   content = function(file){
  #     png(file)
  #     plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input()))
  #     dev.off()}
  # ) # close download handler
  
  mydata <- reactive(list(
    plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())),
    plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input()))
      ) # close list
    ) # close reactive
  nplots <- reactive(length(mydata))
  
  observeEvent(input$download, {
    lapply(1:nplots, function(i){
      ggsave(paste0("yplot",i,".png"), plot(mydata[[i]]))
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({vectorsAll()})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{yld$showme <- tagList(plotOutput("graph1"), plotOutput("graph2"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{yld$showme <- DTOutput("table1")})
  
  output$vectorTable <- renderUI({yld$showme})
  
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    cbind(1:periods(),
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())[,2],
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input())[,2])})})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Suggest you check out the selection widgets in the shinyWidget collection: https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyWidgets/man/shinyWidgetsGallery.html http://shinyapps.dreamrs.fr/shinyWidgets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you can use `ggsave` to save your plots as shown below.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("down", "Download", icon = icon("download"))
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  mydata <- list(cars,pressure,airquality)
  nplots <- length(mydata)
  
  observeEvent(input$down, {
    lapply(1:nplots, function(i){
      ggsave(paste0("yplot",i,".png"), plot(mydata[[i]]))
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server=server)
```

This could be implemented in your MRE as shown below.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyMatrix)
library(shinyjs)
library(DT)
library(ggplot2)

matrix1.input <- function(x){
  matrixInput(x, 
              value = matrix(c(0.2), 2, 1, dimnames = list(c("A","B"),NULL)),
              rows = list(extend = FALSE,  names = TRUE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = FALSE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}

matrix2.input <- function(x,y,z){
  matrixInput(x,
              value = matrix(c(y,z),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL,c("Y","Z"))),
              rows = list(extend = TRUE,  names = FALSE),
              cols = list(extend = FALSE, names = TRUE, editableNames = FALSE),
              class = "numeric")}  

matrix.validate <- function(x,y){
  a <- y        
  a[,1][a[,1]>x] <- x 
  b <- diff(a[,1,drop=FALSE]) 
  b[b<=0] <- NA               
  b <- c(1,b)                 
  a <- cbind(a,b)
  a <- na.omit(a) 
  a <- a[,-c(3),drop=FALSE]         
  return(a)}

vector.base <- function(x,y){
  a <- rep(y,x) 
  b <- seq(1:x) 
  c <- data.frame(x = b, y = a) 
  return(c)}

vector.multi <- function(x,y,z){                                            
  a <- rep(NA, x)
  a[y] <- z       
  a[seq_len(min(y)-1)] <- a[min(y)] 
  if(max(y) < x){a[seq(max(y)+1, x, 1)] <- 0}   
  a <- approx(seq_along(a)[!is.na(a)],a[!is.na(a)],seq_along(a))$y  
  b <- seq(1:x)                                                     
  c <- data.frame(x = b, z = a)                                     
  return(c)}

vector.multiFinal <- function(x,y){
  vector.multi(x,matrix.validate(x,y)[,1],matrix.validate(x,y)[,2])}

matrix.link <- function(x,y){
  observeEvent(input$periods|input$base_input,{
    updateMatrixInput(session,x,value=matrix(c(input$periods,y),1,2,dimnames=list(NULL, c("y","z"))))})}

ui <- 
  pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel("Model"),
    sidebarPanel(uiOutput("Panels")),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(
        tabPanel("Dynamic", value=2,
                 actionButton('showVectorPlotBtn','Vector plots'),
                 actionButton('showVectorValueBtn','Vector values'),
                 
                 actionButton("download", "Download"), 
                 
                 uiOutput("vectorTable")),
        id = "tabselected")
    ) # close main panel
  ) # close page with sidebar

server <- function(input,output,session)({
  periods       <- reactive(input$periods)
  base_input    <- reactive(input$base_input)
  vector_input  <- reactive(input$vector_input)
  vector1_input <- reactive(input$vector1_input)
  yld           <- reactiveValues()
  
  vectorVariable <- function(x,y){
    if(input$showVectorBtn == 0) vector.base(input$periods,x)
    else vector.multiFinal(input$periods,matrix.validate(input$periods,y))}
  
  output$Panels <- renderUI({
    tagList( 
      conditionalPanel(
        condition="input.tabselected==2",
        sliderInput('periods','',min=1,max=120,value=60),
        matrix1.input("base_input"),
        useShinyjs(),
        actionButton('showVectorBtn','Show'), 
        actionButton('hideVectorBtn','Hide'),
        actionButton('resetVectorBtn','Reset'),
        hidden(uiOutput("Vectors"))))})
  
  renderUI({
    matrix.link("vector_input",input$base_input[1,1])
    matrix.link("vector1_input",input$base_input[2,1])})
  
  output$Vectors <- renderUI({input$resetVectorBtn
    tagList(matrix2.input("vector_input",input$periods,input$base_input[1,1]),
            matrix2.input("vector1_input",input$periods,input$base_input[2,1]))})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorBtn,{shinyjs::show("Vectors")})
  observeEvent(input$hideVectorBtn,{shinyjs::hide("Vectors")})
  
  output$graph1 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())))
  output$graph2 <- renderPlot(plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input())))
  
  # output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
  #   filename = function() {paste("yieldVector","png",sep=".")},
  #   content = function(file){
  #     png(file)
  #     plot(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input()))
  #     dev.off()}
  # ) # close download handler
  
  mydata <- reactive(list(
  
    data.frame(vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())),
    data.frame(vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input()))
  ) # close list
  ) # close reactive
  nplots <- reactive(length(mydata()))
  
  observeEvent(input$download, {
    lapply(1:nplots(), function(i){
      ggsave(paste0("yplot",i,".png"), plot(mydata()[[i]]))
    })
  }, ignoreInit = TRUE)
  
  
  output$table1 <- renderDT({vectorsAll()})
  
  observeEvent(input$showVectorPlotBtn,{yld$showme <- tagList(plotOutput("graph1"), plotOutput("graph2"))},ignoreNULL = FALSE)
  observeEvent(input$showVectorValueBtn,{yld$showme <- DTOutput("table1")})
  
  output$vectorTable <- renderUI({yld$showme})
  
  vectorsAll <- reactive({
    cbind(1:periods(),
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[1,1],vector_input())[,2],
          vectorVariable(input$base_input[2,1],vector1_input())[,2])})})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Your example works great, just what I need. The complete App the MWE is extracted from uses ggplot2 so your solution is good. However, I'm having difficulty implementing this suggestion in my original MWE. Please see my edited question with my non-working attempt to incorporate ggsave, in case anyone sees a solution. Probably an error in reactivity chain and I've been fooling around for a solution with no luck yet.

Comment: There are many posts on-line asking basically this same question but the answers are cumbersome, complicated, or inadequate such as creating a zip file for all the plots or fitting all plots onto 1 PDF. I hope many others find this sleek solution helpful for them too!

Comment: This ggsave method works well. However, the downloadHandler function does a terrific user-friendly job of prompting the user for the directory to save the download to. Would you know how to do the same (downloading of multiple PNG files with one click) using downloadHandler instead of ggplot? I've been trying to this without muck luck so far.

Comment: I can download one file with downloadhandler using `onclick()` from `shinyjs`.  However, I don't know how to pass a series of IDs to `onclick()`.  Someone with good javascript knowledge could be able to do it.